# Flyway Migration: NamedParameterJdbcTemplate

Tags: java, spring-jdbc, flyway

Is there anyway to create a flyway migration class utilizing the `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` rather than the standard `JdbcTemplate` that comes across from the implementation of `SpringJdbcMigration`?

I have an upgrade I need to run where I need to convert a column type from text to integer (Replacing a string value with an internal id associated with that value.)

The way I'm doing this is temporarily storing the string values for a reverse lookup, deleting the column and re-adding it as the proper type, and then running an UPDATE call to add in the appropriate ID to the records. I have code similar to the following I want to execute as part of the migration:

```
String sql = "UPDATE my_table SET my_field = :my_field WHERE my_id IN (:my_ids)";
MapSqlParameterSource source = new MapSqlParameterSource();
source.addValue("my_field", someIntValue); // the internal id of the string I want to use.
source.addValue("my_ids", someListOfPKIds); // List of PK ids. 
namedTemplate.update(sql,source); //namedTemplate is a NamedParameterJdbcTemplate
```

However, it seems as if I can't take advantage of the NamedParameterJdbcTemplate. Am I incorrect in this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Flyway sources they [create a new JdbcTemplate in SpringJdbcMigrationExecutor](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/blob/master/flyway-core/src/main/java/org/flywaydb/core/internal/resolver/spring/SpringJdbcMigrationExecutor.java)

However you can try creating a new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate in your migration given the classic JdbcTemplate. Check [this constructor](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/3.2.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.html#NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcOperations)). E.g. `new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(jdbcTemplate)`